# While using Biopython: NameError: name 'pubmed_id' is not defined even though it has been previously defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, bioinformatics, biopython

So I'm trying to retrieve some data from NCBI. The code I had previously written was rewritten by a much more experienced programmer, but it was not returning results in the format I wanted, so I made some modifications/additions:

```
for plant, disease in plant_disease_list:
    search_query = generate_search_query(plant, disease)
    handle1 = Entrez.esearch(db="pmc", term=search_query, retmax="10")
    record1 = Entrez.read(handle1)
    pubmed_ids = record1.get("IdList")
    if pubmed_id in pubmed_ids=="":
     print("Plant: {} Disease: {} PubmedID: DOI:".format(plant, disease))
    else:

     for pubmed_id in pubmed_ids:
       handle2 = Entrez.esummary(db="pmc", id=pubmed_id)
       records = Entrez.read(handle2)
       for record in records:
          doi = record.get("DOI")
          print("Plant: {} Disease: {} PubmedID: {} DOI: http://doi.org/{}".format(plant, disease, pubmed_id, doi))
```

where plant_disease_list is a previously defined list. The only problem is, with this code I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraperscript_python.py", line 28, in <module>
    if pubmed_id in pubmed_ids=="":
NameError: name 'pubmed_id' is not defined
```

If I remove the if/else loop, and go back to the regular nested for loop, I don't get a syntax error, but the code doesn't print the data I want, i.e. it prints data for only those plant-disease pairs for which a PMID was found. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: `    if pubmed_id in pubmed_ids=="":` looks odd to me. What do you want to express? Think about `    if pubmed_id in pubmed_ids:` or `    if pubmed_ids=="":`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the place of 
'if pubmed_id in pubmed_ids=="":'

```
for plumbed_id in plumbed_ids:
      if plumbed_id == "":
           print("Plant: {} Disease: {} PubmedID: DOI:".format(plant, disease))
else:
    your code here..
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not defined when you first come across that statement `if pubmed_id in pubmed_ids=="":`.

Only afterwards, when the loop over `pubmed_ids` has been executed at least once does `pubmed_id` have a value.

In addition, `if pubmed_id in pubmed_ids=="":` is nonsensical.